# webview_flutter target _blank is not working

Tags: flutter

I am using `webview_flutter 0.3.3+1`, my initialUrl loads fine, It contains various links, when clicking on a link it navigates properly but if a link has target set to _BLANK,  it doesn't do anything.

```
WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://SOME_URL',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
)
```

This Works

```
<a href="http://example.com">Link A</a>
```

below doesn't work, it should open external browser but click doesn't take anywhere

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_BLANK">Link B</a>
```

Comment: I think this is a missing feature. Please create an issue in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: @zoechi done https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28875 , I will update here once it is implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in `webview_flutter v0.3.19+6`

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/2500